# What are the methods to find approximatly the 5th roots of an equations

Tags: functions, continuity, roots

By which method, can I find the nearest root of : $x^5−2x+1.1=0$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might try Newton's method.  Or the Maclaurin series of the root (that is $0$ for $a=0$) of 
$x^5 - 2 x + a$ as a function of $a$, which is

$$x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {{5 k} \choose k} \dfrac{a^{4k+1}}{2(4k+1) 32^k}$$

EDIT:  If, as Antonio Vargas suggested, you expand around $a=1$ rather than $a=0$, the formula isn't so pretty.  I get for the first few terms (where $r$ is the root you want at $a=1$)
$$\eqalign{
x&=r+\frac{a-1}{ 5\,{r}^{3}+5\,{r}^{2}+5\,r-3}\cr
&+ \frac{10 r^3 (a-1)^2}{(5\,{r}^{3}+5\,{r}^{2}+5\,r-3)^3}\cr
&+ \frac{(200 r^6+50 r^5+50 r^4+50 r^3-30 r^2) (a-1)^3}{(5\,{r}^{3}+5\,{r}^{2}+5\,r-3)^5}\cr
&+ \frac{(5000\,{r}^{9}+2500\,{r}^{8}+2625\,{r}^{7}+2750\,{r}^{6}-1125\,{r}^{5}+
100\,{r}^{4}-25\,{r}^{3}-150\,{r}^{2}+45\,r) (a-1)^4}{(5\,{r}^{3}+5\,{r}^{2}+5\,r-3)^7}\cr
&+ \frac{(140000\,{r}^{12}+105000\,{r}^{11}+120000\,{r}^{10}+135125\,{r}^{9}-
17625\,{r}^{8}+12750\,{r}^{7}-2350\,{r}^{6}-17700\,{r}^{5}+5100\,{r}^{
4}-190\,{r}^{3}-90\,{r}^{2}+135\,r-27)(a-1)^5}{(5\,{r}^{3}+5\,{r}^{2}+5\,r-3)^9}
\cr&+ \ldots}
$$

Comment: I this case I would suggest expanding around $a=1$ rather than $a=0$ since $x^5-2x+1$ has $x=1$ as a root (so the rest can be expressed using the quartic formula).  This should yield a better approximation using fewer terms of the series.

Comment: Oh man that's ugly. +1!

Answer (score 0):

One of the more popular methods is [Newton's Method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) There also exists other methods that converge to the root more slowly than Newton's Method, such as the Bisection Method, Fixed Point Method, etc...

Answer (score 0):

One method is the so-called "bisection" method.  This is essentially a binary search on the space of possible roots.  Say you want to find $x$ such that $P(x) = 0$, and you have some $a$ such that $P(a) < 0$ and $b$ such that $P(b) > 0$.  Then there must be a root somewhere between $a$ and $b$.  So calculate $P\left(\frac{b-a}2\right)$ and see if it is positive or negative. (If it's zero, you win.)  If it's negative, you now know that the root lies between $\frac{b-a}2$ and $b$; if positive you know that the root lies between $a$ and $\frac{b-a}2$.  You can repeat this as many times as desired, cutting the size of the interval by half each time.

For fifth-degree polynomials it's not hard to come up with the initial $a$ and $b$: just take $a$ to be a large negative number, and $b$ a large positive number.

Often a better method is the Newton-Raphson method.  In this method you guess a root, say $g_0$.  If $P(g_0)$ is zero, you win.  But if not, then you calculate the line that is tangent to $P$ at the point $(g_0, P(g_0))$  and extend this line until it intersects the $x$-axis. The idea is that the graph of $P$ was heading toward the $x$-axis in some direction, and the tangent line is heading in more or less the same direction, so the place where the line reaches the axis, say $g_1$, should be a better approximation of the root than $g_0$ was.

If you work out the geometry, the tangent line has slope $P'(g_0)$ (where $P'$ is the derivative of $P$) and its equation is $y - P(g_0) = P'(g_0)\cdot(x - g_0)$. We want to find the intersection of this line with the line $y=0$, which occurs at $$x=g_0-\frac{P(g_0)}{P'(g_0)}.$$

This value of $x$ is the new guess $g_1$; you repeat this process, producing guesses that are (one hopes) closer and closer to the actual root.

The derivative of the fifth-degree polynomial $P(x) = a_5x^5 + a_4x^4 + a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x+a_0$ is the fourth-degree polynomial
$P'(x) = 5a_5x^4 + 4a_4x^3 + 3a_3x^2 + 2a_2x + a_1$.  For your example $P(x) = x^5−2x+1.1$, so the derivative $P'(x)$ is simply $5x^4-2$.  So for your example the Newton-Raphson method looks like this:  Make an initial guess $g$, say zero.  Then repeatedly calculate

$$ g_{next} = g - \frac{g^5-2g+1.1}{5g^4-2}$$

until it seems like $g$ is pretty close to a root.